# Вывод содержимого из нескольких моделей с сортировкой по дате Django

Tags: python, django

У меня существует три разные модели

```
class Modal_one(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Modal_too(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Modal_free(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

И таких примерно их три или более. Мне нужно как то выводить записи из них с сортировкой по дате. При этом вывод должен быть примерно таким:
Modal_one Article  -> Modal_too Post -> Modal_free Article Примерно в таком порядке.
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вам сначала нужно вывести отсортированные по дате элементы `Modal_one`, затем `Modal_too` и потом `Modal_free`? Если я понял неправильно, значит вам нужно указывть больше вводных данных. Что за Article, Post ?

Comment: Мне нужно вывести их как бы не тремя разными блоками а одним но с сортировкой по дате. То есть получается как бы вперемешку где будут идти записи по дате. К примеру Model_one от 26.01.23 потом Modal_too 26.01.23 и так далее.
Article, Post это что то типа заголовка.

Comment: в джанге есть встроенный метод [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) с помощью которого можно объединить несколько кверисетов, а затем применить сортировку по той же самой дате, например.

Comment: Да кажется это именно то что я искал, но гугл почему то не помог мне в этом вопросе. Спасибо вам.

Comment: старайтесь гуглить на английском, ибо на нашем родном это пустая трата времени.